# How do I highlight the Search String in mysql result?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code so far

```
    <form method="post" name="search">
      <input type="search" name="k" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?
$skw = $_POST['k'];
if(isset($_POST['k'])){
$connect = mysql_connect('*', '*', '*')or die('Could not execute command. Please contact a administrator.');
mysql_select_db('*')or die('No database');
$query = "SELECT * FROM *** WHERE items LIKE '%$skw%'";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"3\">";
    echo "\"" . $skw . "\"";

        if(empty($result)){echo " Not Found!";}else{

            echo " Found In";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "<font color=\"#CC0000\">" . $row['tub_id'] . "</font>";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['items'];
            echo "</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

}}?>
```

How do I highlight the $skw in the result? I have tried using preg_replace, but i am very new to php and cannot get it to work. I understand that I can use classes to style it.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add a css high lightlight

```
.highlight{background-color: yellow; }
```

then assuming that `$skw` is the search keyword and you will search it in `row['items']`
in your while statement

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<font color=\"#CC0000\">" . $row['tub_id'] . "</font>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        $items = preg_replace("/" . $skw. "/", "<span class='highlight'>'" . $skw . "</span>",$row['items']);
        echo $items;
        echo "</td></tr>";

}
```

then some notes are: don't use the `<font>` tag. -_-
and `mysql_*` is deprecated.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class

css sytle:

```
.hihglight{background-color: yellow;}
```

php code:

```
echo "<span class='hihglight'>{$skw}</span>";
```

As side Note: Mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

A useful link [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)